# Increase coloumn width of android tablelayout with gesture

Tags: android, gesture, android-tablelayout

I want to Increase width of Android Table Layout with finger touch movement.
I tried it with TouchListener and Gesture. But did not getting the exact result.
Please share some idea.

Comment: If you add the exact code that gave you the result that is 'not getting the exact result' it would be more helpful to the community and may facilitate a more accurate response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this using GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener. From here you can get the gesture related information as follows :-
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html

Here you will get the Methods as follows:-

```
   public boolean  onScroll (MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY)
```

Inside this Method you need to add the distanceX to width of your coloumn view.

```
like TextView_1.setWidth(TextView_1.getWidth()+Integer.parseInt(distanceX));
```

Hope you will get a clue from here.

you can check this link as reference example of gesture detector

http://www.androidsnippets.com/gesturedetector-and-gesturedetectorongesturelistener